# Next/Previous navigation of an Observable

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I have an observable of blog posts, converted from an array:

```
let posts = Rx.Observable.fromArray(blogPosts)
```

And two observables `nextClicks` and `prevClicks` of button click events for next/previous navigate respectively:

What I want is:

1. Initially the `posts` observable emits the very first post and
   then wait for click events
2. `posts` emits next post when `nextClicks` emits (repeat current post
   if no next available)
3. `posts` emits prev post when `prevClicks` emits (repeat current post
   if no prev available)

And I'm not sure if this is possible:

4. Two observables `postNextable` and `postPrevable`, derived from
   `posts`, indicating whether there is a next/prev post available in
   `posts` respectively

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do 1, 2, 3 and 4. For number 4, I wonder how you plan to use those observables.

One way which only uses pure functions and no subjects is :

```
var blogPosts$ = Rx.Observable.just(blogPosts);
var index$ = Rx.Observable.merge(nextClicks, prevClicks)
             .withLatestFrom(blogPosts$, function(ev, blogPosts){return {posts: blogPosts, ev : ev};})
             .scan(function(index, posts_and_ev){
                     return isNextClick(posts_and_ev.ev) && isNextable(posts_and_ev.posts, index) ? index + 1 
                           :isPrevClick(posts_and_ev.ev) && isPrevable(posts_and_ev.posts, index) ? index - 1
                           :index
                   }, 0);
var currentPost$ = index$.withLatestFrom(blogPosts$, function (index, blogPost){return blogPost[index]; }).startWith(blogPosts[0]);
var postNextable = index$.withLatestFrom(blogPosts$, function (index, blogPost){return isNextable(blogPost, index);});
var postPrevable = index$.withLatestFrom(blogPosts$, function (index, blogPost){return isNextable(blogPost, index);})
```

The output you seek is named here `currentPost$`.

Code test included thereafter. `isNextable`, `isNextClick`, `isPrevable`, `isPrevClick` have obvious semantics, and are easy to write (for example discriminating on key codes or button ids or else for your `next` and `prev` events). [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/4e4s218u/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer and the sample code. These code is what I was looking for! By the way, for the #4, I use those two observables to display proper CSS style (enable/disable) of each button.